# 16.04 -- Reassign Ctrl + Alt + Numpad 0 (minimize window) shortcut

Tags: command-line, unity, shortcut-keys

Is there a way for me to change the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> shortcut using the terminal?

I tried listing all `gsettings` and `dconf` shortcuts using the [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725611/how-to-search-through-all-keyboard-shortcuts-that-use-a-certain-key), but didn't find the window placement ones except:

`org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-maximized ['<Control><Alt>KP_5']`

We use this shortcut in Blender, so I would like to change it or unassigned it in Ubuntu 16.04/Unity.

I need a terminal solution because I need to apply the change to a lab full of computers.

Comment: You might be able to change it with CCSM, if nothing else. I'll check once I'm at my machine later.

Comment: This feature of CCSM is well explained in https://askubuntu.com/a/116889/507051.

Comment: This appears to be a GUI solution which doesn't help me. I need a terminal/command line solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `gsettings list-recursively | grep minimize` to find the gsettings key you're looking for: `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings minimize`

If you wanted to disable it, you could use

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings minimize "['disabled']"
```

Comment: This isn't the problem.  E.g: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings minimize
['<Control><Alt>m']`

Comment: @43Tesseracts actually, I think it is. When I `gsettings list-recursively | awk '/hotkey/||/keybinding/||/media-key/' | grep KP_0` I get `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings minimize ['<Control><Alt>KP_0']` don't you?

Comment: You're totally right.  I had already fixed this on the computer I was testing on (had changed it to Ctrl + Alt + M).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xbindkeys` to reach your goal. I'd try it out on one of the lab computers, write a script to automate the necessary steps and run this script on every computer. Read [`man xbindkeys`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xbindkeys.1.html) and the configuration example displayed by `xbindkeys --defaults`. Here's something to start with:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt install xbindkeys xbindkeys-config # install packages
echo -e '# descriptive comment\n"command --to execute"\n   Control + Alt + Mod2 + KP_Insert' > ~/.xbindkeysrc # create ~/.xbindkeysrc
echo -e '[Desktop Entry]\nType=Application\nName=xbindkeys\nExec=xbindkeys\nX-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true' > ~/.config/autostart/xbindkeys.desktop # autostart xbindkeys using a .desktop file
```

You can use `xbindkeys -k` to determine keycodes like `Mod2 + KP_Insert` for <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>. Don't forget to add `xbindkeys` to your autostart commands, I added the command to create a `.desktop` file above which should be working. If it's not, try other solutions from here: [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)